# Altering term_id and name via $wpdb class

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, wpdb

```
$s = $_POST['submitterms'];
$querystr = "
            SELECT $wpdb->terms.*
            FROM $wpdb->terms
            WHERE
            lower($wpdb->terms.name) like '%$s%'
         ";
$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
echo '<ul>';
$x = 0;
while ($pageposts[$x]) {
  $post = $pageposts[$x];
  echo '<li>';
  echo '<a href="' . $post->term_id . '">' . $post->name . '</a>';
  echo '</li>';
  $x++;
}

echo '</ul>';
```

I'm able to get term names that contains the characters i typed into the text box.

But what i want to do is changing `term_id AS id AND name AS value` so that i can pass the variables like:

```
$post->id
$post->value
//i.e
echo '<a href="'.$post->id.'">'.$post->value.'</a>';
```

I guess i need to change the MySQL code. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily. Your query should be:

```
$querystr = "SELECT `term_id` AS `id`, `name` AS `value`, `slug`, `term_group` FROM {$wpdb->terms} WHERE lower($wpdb->terms.name) like '%$s%'";
```

See, here i've mentioned the name of the fields needed. For any other fields, you need to explicitly mention the field names.